# Is it possible to get internal ip through external inside private network?

Tags: windows, networking, ip

The doubt is in the title, as simple as that. Is it possible to get the internal IP through the external IP inside my network?

### Scenario

---

I am building a whatsapp bot that will assist the employees in my company to solve problems faster or to aid us in a **faster approach** but, the problem is, the company is mostly not used to technical commands to get us the ip so we could provide a remote assistance.

A simple command such as **start > cmd > ipconfig** and search for the IPv4 could become a hassle to these people. So, to make this simpler I though in asking for them to access a website that provides the external IP so we can track back the internal and make it easier to the user so the instruction would be basically this:

1. Access https://whatismyipaddress.com/
2. Send us the IPv4 number

All the computers are inside our private network.

If there is a way to get the internal IP through the external and avoid the headache to the user it would highly benefits us since we are somewhat technical in the area (but not to this extent to find the ip).

I was trying to do so through traceroute, ping, tracert but with no success so far.

Is this even possible?

**All the computers in the network are with windows installed, either 7 or 10.**

Comment: I don't know any way to do that. Are you on the same network of them ? Because I don't understand why you need their local ip address if you are on a different network. If you are not on the same network you can't reach them by private address.

Comment: It would for remote access through the default windows default app.

Comment: Ok. Question is: do you have to pass through internet to reach them, or are they on the same network than you ?

Comment: all in the same network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why in the name of sanity are you doing it this way?
You ultimately seem to want the internal ip.

If you setup a help website on your internal network, when they connect you will automatically get there internal IP address.

For example you could write a simple php app, and it would have access to their internal ip.  Then you could have the php script send you their IP via any means you find convenient.  You could even have it email you their IP.

Am I missing something?

Locally it should be as simple as referencing

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

You don't have to echo the IP address to the screen if you don't want to have it shown.

Comment: Hmmm, this is a great idea! If this is possible through it, it is worth the attempt!

Comment: @Banns  Referencing  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] should be enough to grab their IP.  Then you can write further code to send it wherever you want.  PHP has built-in email support, even though it is kind of primitive it works.

Comment: I think this will do the trick. Thanks @cybernard.